# How can I raise a concrete bridge footing two inches?

Tags: concrete

I have two existing concrete footers from the previous bridge that are not leveled.  I thought about using hydraulic cement to level the top of it.  The left side needs to be about 2 inches higher than what it currently is, while the right side can remain the same.

The existing footers are 9 by 47 inches. The are about 3 feet deep into the ground and edge of the creek. The bridge will be made of wood. I used 3 2x12 10 ft long as arched trusses. I will be using 1x6 deck boards as the walking platform and they will be 4 feet long. Mainly foot traffic and a push mower. I just need to level the footers so when I anchor the bridge to it it doesn’t look like crap. I thought about shims but with the left side being 2 inches too low it would look like crap as well. My question is would you use self leveling cement to level the footers or do you suggest a different route?

I’ll add a photo of the footers when I get home from work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If this is related to Home Improvement, you should add some images showing us why. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: How big are the footings? How wide is the bridge? What will the bridge deck be made of? What kind of traffic will go on the bridge?

Comment: what kind of suggestions are you seeking? ... you did not indicate that you are having any problems

Comment: @jsotola As I understand it, the question is "Should I use hydraulic cement to raise the left footer to match the right footer of my 10-foot bridge?" But without knowing a lot more details, it is impossible to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: How about notching the 2x12 so they are only 10" over the taller footer?

Comment: Hello again. It looks like you now have [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/103918) separate [accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/103922/justin); you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please do [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Shoot, I thought you had uneven footings _on one side_ of the water. It would make no difference to me that the bridge is slightly out of level from end to end. It's more important that the ends land on the ground.

Comment: Justin, it was suggested that you take the tour in a comment above. Please do so and you'll know not to post information that belongs in your question in an answer.

Comment: You need to use treated wood or try to treat existing wood , also screws should be stainless.  I built a similar bridge using 2 X 2 treated decking; some decking rotted and most deck screws rusted away after 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd try to pour new masonry in such a thin quantity. It's likely to crack up due to moisture, vibration, etc. Hydraulic cement is more of a patchwork product, in my experience, and self-leveling cement is way off the mark.

I'd do one of these:

- Lay a paver brick (or a series of them) on the existing footing using landscape block adhesive, bolts and expansion anchors, or other retainers. This should be just large enough to support your bridge so as to not look gaudy.
- Build a wooden "leg" that coordinates with your bridge. It should be mounted flush on the outside as a deck post would, or slightly inboard, to minimize its appearance.
- Fabricate a metal leg. Box tubing and/or angle stock and a few bolts would do well. Either let this rust for a nice patina or protect it with enamel or paint-on galvanizer.

To tell you which I'd select I'd need to see more of the situation.